# multiprocessing and python

Tags: python, dialog, subprocess

I can't find what is wrong on this code:

```
def CLOSE(self,PROCESS):
    state=getattr(PROCESS,"is_alive()")
    while state==True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        state=getattr(PROCESS,"is_alive()")

    self.window_waiting.hide()

def on_button_act_clicked(self, menuitem, data=None):
    WAITING = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.window_waiting.show())
    SYNC = multiprocessing.Process(target=SYNC_program_data, args=(self,))
    close = multiprocessing.Process(target=CLOSE, args=(self,SYNC,))

    close.start()
    WAITING.start()
    SYNC.start()

    WAITING.join()
    SYNC.join()
    close.join()
```

This should open the window self.window_waiting , start the definition SYNC_program_data, and when SYNC_program_data ends it should close the window self.window_waiting.

but im getting this error

```
  File "./fresh_install", line 1079, in CLOSE
state=getattr(PROCESS,"is_alive()")
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'is_alive()'
```

so the window is opend, closed, and the SYNC_program_data runs...

I'm trying to do a waiting dialog in python and GTK+.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getattr` in that way (where did you learn that, anyway?). Use simply `PROCESS.is_alive()`.

And really, instead of your `while` loop, just call:

```
PROCESS.join()
```

which will block until your process terminates.

Comment: it doesn't works, it does the same thing that before, but now witht this error                                                          line 155, in is_alive
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only test a child process'
AssertionError: can only test a child process

Comment: @user3672754 - the assert means exactly what it says... you've passed the SYNC process object to the close process. They are siblings. process control has to stay with the parent.

Comment: @tdelaney: Good spotting, I hadn't noticed that.